# Finding the limit of a sequence $n^{\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How would one find the limit of the following sequence.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{\sin(\pi/n)}$$
I did the following.

$$e^{\ln(n)\sin(\pi/n)}$$

then I did

$$\frac{\ln n }{\sin\frac{\pi}n}$$

But the intermediate form now would be infinity/0 and does not seem to work.

Comment: Yes the algebraic rearrangement can be a pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have $\frac{\ln n}{\csc \pi/n}$ instead.  Now apply L'Hopital.

Comment: thanks, how stupid from me ^^ (+1)

Comment: thanks that make snes michel

Comment: Ok I applied the hospital rule and got $\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\csc(\pi/n)\cot(\pi/n)\pi(1/-n^2)}$

Comment: Then one more time and I got $\frac{1}{(1/-n^2)\csc(\pi/n)\cot(pi/n)\cot(pi/n)+-\csc^2(pi/n)csc(pi/2)(\pi/-n^2)}$

Comment: But here I am not sure what to do...

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Note that $0\le \sin\frac \pi n<\frac \pi n$ and hence $1\le n^{\sin \frac\pi n}\le \left(\sqrt[n]n\right)^\pi$.